# Jquery .click hide function for closing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I prepared fragment of my page to show you my problem:
[a link](http://www.informacjakrd.pl/small.html)

On the bottom is show small red window named div "pomocnik"
In Chrome browser click on the "close" icon do it works, but IE does the work prepared for clicking in the text inside DIV
`onclick="document.location.href('http://www.google.com')`
so it open new page.

IE has detected onclick for DIV but Chrome detected more in detail for image.
My idea is to close window after clicking on close button.

```
$('#close').click(function() {
    //var g = document.getElementById("pomocnik");
    //g.style.display = 'none';
    $('#pomocnik').hide(2000);
    $('#konsul').click = null;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the event (click onto close image) first calls the event handler which hides your div, but then bubbles up to the containing div and starts the default action for it (open the link). Try the following:

```
$('#close').click(function(e) {
     //var g= document.getElementById("pomocnik");
     //g.style.display= 'none';
     e.stopPropagation(); //this will prevent the event from bubbling up to the containing div
     $('#pomocnik').hide(2000);
     //$('#konsul').click=null;
 });
```

Comment: Thank you!I used your tip and now close icon only close window without redirection.